# retrieve distinct values with different fields name and type from two table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

- table1 :id,year,month,...
- table2 :id,date,...

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the distinct values of months from both tables for a specific year (example:2017) and for a specific id(**note that table1 have year and month as separate fields while table2 have a complete date as a single field**)

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT month 
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1.month = table2.(to_char(date,'mm'))
 WHERE table1.year=2017
   AND id=406;
```

I am getting this error:

```
 ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
```

as for the scenario, table1 contains a piece of pay element and table2 contain another pay element, an employee could have an entry in both for the same month or a unique entry in one of the tables for another month, the issue is that I need to count the number of months paid out of 12 (I do not want the same month to be repeated)

Answer (score 2):

The Alias will come inside the function call.

You probably want:

```
select distinct t1.month
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.month = to_char(t2.date, 'mm')
where t1.year = 2017
    and id = 406;
```

Also, use short meaningful aliases to aid readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query.  Note that joining the two tables by date should require comparing *both* the year and the month.

```
select distinct t1.month
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t1.month = to_char(t2.date, 'mm') and
       t1.year = to_char(t2.date, 'yyyy')
where t1.year = 2017 and
      id = 406;
```

You should change your table design and not store the day, month, and year in separate columns.